# macOS Ventura 13.0 does not show .Trash folder in my Home directory

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, ventura, apple-silicon

In Finder, .Trash does not appear.

[image]

But on Terminal, I can see the directory.

[image]

I'd like to add Trash on the sidebar.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have just stumbled upon a simple way to add Trash to the Finder's sidebar in Ventura 13.2.1:

1. Click on the Trash icon in the dock to open Finder showing the Trash
2. Either select "Add to Sidebar" from the File menu on the menu bar or use the shortcut Ctrl-Cmd-T

Comment: Works perfectly on Venture 13.4! And has the Trash icon in the sidebar too unlike other methods.

Answer (score 1):

The Finder based view of Trash is only available via the Bin on the Dock, so Finder will not show `~/.Trash`. Essentially this is a design choice by Apple.

`~/.Trash` may not be the only Trash folder in the system, and the job of the Bin is to present a consolidated view of all the files **that you have permission for**, in all the Trashes. This is because it's quite possible for other users to also Trash files on those other volumes, that you are not allowed to access.

Each attached volume will have its own Trash. This can be tested by creating a new APFS volume in the existing container for your system, or connecting an external Volume, copying files to it, and then deleting them with Finder. They'll show up in the Bin, but not in `~/.Trash`. They will however show up with `sudo ls -lRa /Volumes/VOL/.Trashes`. You'll see a subfolder under `.Trashes`, named for your UID (`501`, if you're the only user of the system), which contains the deleted files. So other users would trash files to subfolders for their UID. Again, this is why `sudo` would be needed because you are potentially not the only user.

Edit March 23:

Further info, now possible in Ventura (maybe earlier but I can't check)  as mentioned in the better answer above, and also in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/456614/221742

Comment: It's worth noting that "Bin" is a macOS Localization for British English (and Australian English); but it's not used in the US English OS.

Comment: @benwiggy Ah good to know!

Comment: I've always thought the term 'Bin' to be an example of over-translation. I'm a Brit & I still think of it as Trash, even though i'm aware it's a US not British word. It reminds me of a trip to Italy - I just couldn't understand the menus provided for English speakers, because 'meat sauce with paste' does not accurately convey the difference between lasagne & spaghetti bolognese. I had to use the Italian menu to see what I was ordering ;)